# Flasgger - Add bearer authorization

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi, flasgger

I am running a flask app and using flasgger to generate Swagger Specs as well as a Swagger UI. My API requires the requests to be authenticated using a bearer token. I am able to get the button on the page and set the token. But it is not sent through the requests. I am using OpenAPI 3.0.3. Below is my code:

```
from flasgger import Swagger

swagger_template = {
    'components': {
        'securitySchemes': {
            'bearerAuth': {
                'type': 'http',
                'scheme': 'bearer',
                'bearerFormat': 'JWT'
            }
        },
        'security': {
            'bearerAuth': []
        }
    }
}

# Register controllers
api = Api(app)
swagger = Swagger(app=app, config={
    'headers': [

    ],
    'title': 'Model Design Application API',
    'specs': [
        {
            'endpoint': 'apispec',
            'route': '/apispec.json'
        }
    ],
    'openapi': '3.0.3'
}, template=swagger_template)
```

This is the token to be set in the Swagger UI:

[image]

This is the UI I get in Swagger:

[image]

This is the apispec.json that is generated:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "User": {
      "properties": {
        "username": {
          "default": "Steven Wilson", 
          "description": "The name of the user", 
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "info": {
    "description": "powered by Flasgger", 
    "termsOfService": "/tos", 
    "title": "Model Design Application API", 
    "version": "0.0.1"
  }, 
  "openapi": "3.0.3", 
  "paths": {
    "/profile": {
      "get": {
        "description": "It works also with swag_from, schemas and spec_dict<br/>", 
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A single user item", 
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "summary": "This examples uses FlaskRESTful Resource"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "security": {
    "bearerAuth": []
  }, 
  "securitySchemes": {
    "bearerAuth": {
      "bearerFormat": "JWT", 
      "scheme": "bearer", 
      "type": "http"
    }
  }
}
```

Please advice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fixed it by adding 'security': [
            {
                'bearerAuth': []
            }
        ] to swagger_template

Comment: that comment should be an answer (it's ok and encouraged to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 4):

For adding header in Flasgger API, do the following changes:

```
SWAGGER_TEMPLATE = {"securityDefinitions": {"APIKeyHeader": {"type": "apiKey", "name": "x-access-token", "in": "header"}}}

swagger = Swagger(app, template=SWAGGER_TEMPLATE)
```

Here, **x-access-token** is our key name in header. you can change this name according to your requirement.
After this, we need to add this header in our .yml file. Our .yml file will look like this:

```
summary: "Put your summery here."
description: "Put your description here."
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
security:
- APIKeyHeader: ['x-access-token']
responses:
  200:
    description: "Success"
```

Comment: What is "our  .yml file"? Where is it? Where it should be and which service will read it?

Comment: @AntonMakarov ".yml" is api documentation file. we can keep it anywhere in our project directory. example: 
let say our filename is "login_doc.yml". Import this: "
from flasgger.utils import swag_from" then use this code: 

@api.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
@swag_from("path/login_doc.yml")
def login():

Answer (score 1):

Check the working code here

```
template = {
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "XYZ API Docs",
        "description": "API Documentation for XYZ Application",
        "contact": {
            "responsibleOrganization": "",
            "responsibleDeveloper": "",
            "email": "XYZ@XYZ.com",
            "url": "XYZ.com",
        },
        "termsOfService": "XYZ .com",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "basePath": "/api/v1",  # base bash for blueprint registration
    "schemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "Bearer": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "in": "header",
            "description": "\
            JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\""
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
            "Bearer": []
        }
    ]
}

swagger_config = {
    "headers": [

        ],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": 'apispec',
            "route": '/apispec.json',
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],
    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "swagger_ui": True,
    "specs_route": "/api/v1/apispec"
}
```